# Reactive Forms patchValue() in For loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

Following sample code:

```
model={name: "D100"
value: "Dying"};

   for (let key in model) {
            if(this.divisionForm.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                let value = divisionModel[key];
                this.form.patchValue({
                    key: value
                });
            }
        }
```

- Is there any way to achieve the looping object and insert key value pair into the **Angular reactive form's patchValue()**
- I cannot have values to get set in form i can achieve this by manually add setValue() and use destructuring to get the objects and set which leads very long code in bigger forms.

I have structed in this for long time kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply spread your form value and override the properties you want to change.

As a sidenote, `patchValue` is supposed to keep the values of the keys you don't provide, e.g. giving a single key will keep all other keys to their actual value.

Here is a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xlxcic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  constructor() {
    const form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      surname: new FormControl('')
    });

    form.patchValue({
      ...form.value,
      name: 'name of the user'
    });

    form.patchValue({
      surname: 'surname of the user, with name kept'
    });

    console.log(form.value);
  }
```

Comment: trichetriche Thanks for your valuable reply. I would be pleased to have your response. But still your answer doesn't suit my question. My question is that can i achieve that patchValue() insertion in looping concept ? I have tried your technique but still no improvement.

Comment: With two seconds of self thinking, you would probably understand that the second syntax can be used in loops ... But if you want me to be more specific, feel free to post some data and your model, or even a [mcve] of your question on https://stackblitz.com so that I can show you how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

try this, No need to use loop

```
this.form.patchValue(model)
```

For information visit, https://dev.to/crazedvic/using-patchvalue-on-formarrays-in-angular-7-2c8c

Comment: you all right! thankss!